# Списки в c# и как их читать?

Tags: c#, unity3d, list

у меня достаточно лёгий вопрос (наверное), как считать значения с списка при заданном значении? Например у меня есть список, очень большой и я хочу прочитать линию с номером некой переменной.

```
print(dots[i]);
```

Где dots - это список
Где i там номер строки.

Юнити выдает не критическую ошибку:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
```

Parameter name: index

Из неё я понял что такой строки в списке нет, но я проверял с дебагом - значение было 64 и в списке оно было. 
Спасибо.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlanetTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int seed;
    public static Color color;
    public static bool deathGas = false;
    public static float amplitude;
    public static float freq;

    public int dotcount = 0;
    public List<Vector2> chunkdots;
    public GameObject tile;
    public int worldSize;

    private void Awake()
    {
        seed = Random.Range(1, 10000);
        amplitude = Random.Range(8, 100);
        freq = Random.Range(83, 100);

        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        SetPoints();
        StartCoroutine(Generate());
    }
    void SetPoints()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < worldSize; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < worldSize; z++)
            {
                dotcount++;
                Debug.Log(dotcount);
                chunkdots.Add(new Vector2(x * 16, z * 16));
            }
        }


    }

    IEnumerator Generate()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);

        for (int i = 0; i < dotcount; i++)
        {
            int ic = 0;
            ic = dotcount;
            Debug.Log("ic = " + ic);
            Instantiate(tile, new Vector3(chunkdots[ic].x, 0, chunkdots[ic].y), Quaternion.identity);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если у вас 64 элемента в списке, убедитесь, что вы не пытаетесь получить элемент с индексом 64.
64й элемент в списке будет иметь индекс 63, так как индексы начинаются с 0, а не с 1.

Answer (score 2):

Вы во всём цикле присваиваете ic величину массива, тем самым получая `Index was out of range`. последний индекс в массиве из 64 элементов это 63!

```
for (int i = 0; i < chunkdots.Count; i++) {
    Debug.Log("i:"+i+" x:"+chunkdots[i].x+" y:"+chunkdots[i].y);
    Instantiate(tile, new Vector3(chunkdots[i].x, 0, chunkdots[i].y), Quaternion.identity);           
}
```

И считать объём списка отдельной переменной не нужно, у List есть свойство Count, как у обычного массива Lenght.